# Como permitir somente números em um Edit?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Tenho o seguinte código na minha função `IntegerKeyDown` que está no formpai

`If not (CharInSet(KeyChar,['0'..'9']))then
begin
  Key:=0;
  KeyChar:= 0;
end;`

Chamo ele em alguns Edits dos  forms filhos.
Funciona perfeitamente no Windows, mas não funciona no Android.
Não dá erro nenhum, mas não impede de digitar letras e símbolos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar o componente `TNumberBox`. É possível delimitar um *range* de operação (min-máx), assim como validar somente inteiros ou permitir números reais.

[Segue a descrição do componente](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.NumberBox.TNumberBox)

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo XML onde você criou o EditText (no seu layout) adicione:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

dentro dos atributos dele.